# Vim syntax conceal passwords

Tags: vim, passwords, gnupg

I am creating a Vim syntax highlighting file for PGP-encrypted passwords using the format of this post: http://pig-monkey.com/2013/04/password-management-vim-gnupg/. Namely, the syntax is as follows:

```
Super Ecommerce{{{
    user:   foobar
    pass:   g0d
    Comments{{{
        birthday:   1/1/1911
        first car:  delorean
    }}}
}}}
```

Already folding is working with `{{{` and `}}}` to prevent shoulder surfing. However, when an entry is expanded, I would also like to conceal the password with red background and red foreground text, to continue to prevent shoulder surfing when expanded.

Currently, I am solving this by wrapping the password in `(((` and `)))` blocks. This way, I can control which passwords are hidden, and which passwords are not. My Vim syntax for solving this is:

```
set conceallevel=3
syntax region gpgpassPasswords start="\v\(\(\(" end="\v\)\)\)"
highlight link gpgpassPasswords Conceal
highlight gpgpassPasswords ctermbg=red ctermfg=red
```

Our "Super Ecommerce" block would then look like:

```
Super Ecommerce{{{
    user:   foobar
    pass:   (((g0d)))
    ...
```

And `(((g0d)))` would then print as red foreground text on a red background, thus effectively concealing the password from view.

However, I think I would rather just conceal all passwords following `^\s*pass:\s*` without `(((` and `)))`. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the syntax correct for concealing just the password, without also concealing everything else on the line.

How can I conceal just passwords without extra region characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
syn match MyPassword /\%(^\s*pass:\s*\)\@<=\S\+/ conceal cchar=*
setl conceallevel=2 concealcursor=nv
```

This however depends a little on your other syntax rules. With newer Vims you can also just use a `matchadd()` function call.

Comment: Perfect! So the trick was ```\@<=``` to prevent matching everything behind, and only matching from ```\S``` forward. Learned something new. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Use `\zs` (match start) and `\ze` (match end) to limit the matched area:

```
:syntax match gpgpassPasswords /^\s*pass:\s*\zs.*\ze$/
```